# Script to Shutdown/Startup Synapses

Tags: azure-synapse

I'm pretty new to Synapse but we are looking for a script to shutdown/startup Synapse during non business hours.  This is to help reduce our costs during evenings and weekends.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Is anyone aware of a script that could assist with this?

Comment: **Synapses-** Does this mean Synapse SQL pool?

Comment: Yes it would be for a Syapse SQL Pool.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize Azure Synapse pipelines to automate the pausing and resuming of your Synapse Dedicated SQL pool.

In order to do that first you will have to create a pipeline, then identify the list of dedicated SQL pools in your Azure Synapse workspace. Next filter any dedicated SQL pools that you don't want to pause or resume from the list and then loop over each dedicated SQL pool and next check the state of each dedicated SQL pool, evaluate the state of the dedicated SQL pool and make a decision whether to pause or resume the dedicated SQL pool based on the business need.
The pipeline flow looks like below:

[image]

This pipeline flow will utilize below REST API's to list, check state and then pause or resume your Dedicated SQL pools.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/synapse/sql-pools
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/

Here is a public documentation which is a sample demonstration on how to setup the pipeline to automate the process using Synapse pipelines.

[Pause and resume dedicated SQL pools with Synapse Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/how-to-pause-resume-pipelines)

Here is a techcommunity article by one of the MSFT which uses script to automate the pausing and resuming of Synapse Dedicate SQL pools: [Automatic pause all Synapse Pools and keeping your subscription costs under control](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-synapse-analytics-blog/automatic-pause-all-synapse-pools-and-keeping-your-subscription/ba-p/2067298)

Comment: I appreciate the assistance :)